# Изменение фокуса c клавиатуры на Activity для скрытия навигационной панели

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Создали приложение с fullscreen экраном и столкнулся с такой проблемой при вызове клавиатуры навигационная панель остается. Работаю в фрагментах. Использую следующий код для создание fullscreen экрана

```
            @Override
            public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
                super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
                if (hasFocus) {
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    );
                }
            }
```

[image: При переходе на фрагмент с editText]
[image: Ввод значения в editText]
[image: Скрытия клавиатуры в фрагменте путем нажатия треугольника в навигационной панели]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему путем добавления кода для кнопки ок, так же можно переопределить кнопку назад в навигационном меню и то же повесить этот код

```
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.ButtonEdit:
                    setTextButtonAndTextView(0);
                    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    );


                    break;
```